# Box2d slingshot in pinball game

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I am developing a pinball game with box2d physics (with AndEngine framework). I am testing different approaches for implement left and right slingshot: 
- use restitution parameter of the body
- contact listener and then apply linearImpulse to the ball
- some mechanism of using a dynamic body with prismaticJoint which would bounce the ball the other direction (this approach I still didn't tested because is harder to implement)

Any help/examples would be very helpful

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/11/03/develop-a-flash-game-like-angry-birds-using-box2d-predictive-trajectory-line/) is for flash, but it uses JBox2D the physics, so I was able to adapt it to work in AndEngine.  This article shows code for the slingshot as well as the predictive trajectory.  It was all I needed to make a slingshot (that and a good grounding in going from polar to cartesian coordinates).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is slingshot is not the same as slingshots in pinball

Comment: While I'm sorry you weren't able to find a way to adapt this to what you need, I don't think the downvote was necessary.  To each his own, I suppose.